# Suppose $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ is an isomorphism, and $g\in G$. Prove that $\text{ord}(\phi(g))= \text{ord}(g)$.

Tags: group-theory

Here's my attempt:

Let $n$ be the order of $g$. Then $g^n=1$. Now $$1=\phi(1)=\phi(g^n)=\phi(g)^n,$$ so the order of $\phi(g)$ divides the order of $g$; so $\phi(g)k=g$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

What do I do next to get the equality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply the exact same argument with the inverse isomorphism $\phi^{-1} : H \to G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an isomorphism, so go the other way around. Let $k$ be the order of $\phi(g)$, then $\phi(g)^k=1$.

$$1=\phi^{-1}(1)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(g)^k) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(g))^k = g^k$$

So the order of $g$ divides the order of $\phi(g)$. With your result, we can conclude that since both are natural, they have to be the same.

Comment: Ah, I see, very elegant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Since $\phi$ is an *injective* morphism, for every $g \in G$ of finite order we the equality of sets

$$
\{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} : g^n = 1\} = \{m \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} : \phi(g)^m = 1\}
$$
hence they have the same minimum.